# Arcscene export issue: only upper layer showing up

Tags: arcgis-10.1, layers, export, 3d-analyst, arcscene

I have created a 3d visualization with ArcScene 10.1.

I have 1 hillshade of a portion of an area, which take elevation ifno from DEM of the same area. Also, the DEM is coloured and overlayed onto the hillshade. Plus, vectors data are added (i.e., rivers and springline).

Now, I have tried to export the scene as 2D; I have used various format like PDF, TIFF and other formats. The issue is that the exported scene is just the upper layer, i.e., the DEM. The Hillshade as well as the vertoc layers do not show up.

Any insight in to issue?

Comment: Do you have enough rep to post the screen shoot?

Comment: Do you use transparency for the DEM? It often causes export problems.